# Double integral of Dirac Delta Function

Tags: random-variables, dirac-delta

While dealing with an autocorrelation function I ended up with the following:

$ R_{YY}(t+\tau, t)=\int_0^{t+\tau}{\int_0^{t}\delta(v-s)dsdv} , t\ge0  ,\tau\ge0 $

I do not know how to approach this, in $[0,t]\times[0,t+\tau]$ only the line $s=v$ will have contribution so inner integral gives $1$ until $v\le t$ (and $0$ otherwise) for some reason the following seems to be the answer:

$\int_0^{t+\tau}{\int_0^{t}\delta(v-s)dsdv}=t $

But then

$ R_{YY}(t+\tau, t)=t$ does not make any sense at all

(For those who are interested the original problem: "For $0$-mean WSS random process $X(t)$, $R_{XX}(t_1,t_2)=\delta(t_1-t_2)$, $Y(t)=\int_0^tX(v)dv$, is $Y$ WSS?". Integration is a linear operator though not time invariant as it starts from time $0$, so I am not sure )
Could you please help me?

Comment: This is what I get as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that$$\int_0^t\delta(\nu-s)ds = 
\begin{cases}
1\quad \nu\in (0,t) \\
0\quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Thus 
$$\int_0^{t+\tau}{\int_0^{t}\delta(v-s)dsdv} = \int_0^t1d\nu+\int_t^{t+\tau}0d\nu = t$$